# Redis returns an error when attempting to save

Tags: nosql, redis

When running the SAVE command in redis-cli for Redis 1.3.15 it just returns "(error) ERR", BGSAVE does not appear to do anything either. The SHUTDOWN command returns "(error) ERR Errors trying to SHUTDOWN. Check logs.". Killing the Redis process and starting Redis again does not change the save error.

Naturally I have tried to check the logs, but I havent been able to find any. Any hints where I can find the logs or what might be the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

to check where the log files are located you should check the redis.conf file.

If BGSAVE or SAVE are failing there is maybe a problem with permissions of directory or alike, this kind of problems will be reported in the log file of course.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer & a fantastic product, redis rocks!


Didn't have a log setup in redis.conf, that is now done. You are right it is a permission problem:


[3714] 19 Aug 21:39:18 # Failed saving the DB: Permission denied

As far as I can see all permissions on dump.rdb are correct:
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root  76394749 2010-08-18 12:17 dump.rdb


No permissions on directories have been changed since before the error occured.

Is there any docs on what permissions are needed or do you have any other tips what might be the problem?

Comment: The only permission requirement is that Redis should be able to create files in the configured directory, and of course there must not be a file named dump.rdb already that is not can't be overwritten. Probably your Redis is not running as root, but the current file dump.rdb is instead root rw-r-r so there is no way the Redis instance is able to rewrite it.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The problem turned out to be that I stated redis with the incorrect user. Now it all works like a charm.

Comment: Just a note for future Googlers: if your redis-server daemon is having trouble shutting down, this might fix it. Worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: When saving, redis creates a new, temporary file which it must complete writing before it renames to the target file.  So if redis can't create a new file, even if the requested file already exists, the save will fail.